# Difference between eth.newAccount and personel.newAccount

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, private-blockchain, web3.py

Can anyone explain the difference between

```
`eth.accounts.create()` and `eth.personal.newAccount()`
```

and which one we should use and why? As I am new to ethereum so its very confusing for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation the definition for both is a little bit different

---

**eth.accounts**

> The web3.eth.accounts contains functions to generate Ethereum accounts and sign transactions and data.

There is only one paramater which is

- entropy - String (optional): A random strong to increase entropy. If given it should be at least 32 characters. If none is given a random string will be generated using randomhex.

Also `eth.accounts.create()` will return an object that contains

- address - string: The account address.
- privateKey - string: The accounts private key.
- signTransaction(tx [, callback]) - Function: The function to sign transactions.
- sign(data) - Function: The function to sign transactions

---

**eth.personal**

> The web3.eth.personal package allows you to interact with the Ethereum node’s accounts.

There is also only one parameter but it allows you to set the password

- password - String: The password to encrypt this account with.

And you only get a string as return which is

- Promise returns String: The address of the newly created account.

---

There is not much more information about it, but I guess you would use the one that suits your need the most. In most case you should probably use `eth.accounts` because it gives you back much more information.

Source : [web3.js - Ethereum JavaScript API](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/)

Comment: account created by using eth.accounts.create(), not showing in eth.accounts list. Also Is there any need to unlock that newly created account (by using eth.accounts.create())

Comment: @AmitSharma The `getAccounts` method returns a promise are you sure you're waiting for it?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the `personal` module lets you interact with "locked" accounts which require a password to take an action. The `eth.accounts` module lets you interact with already unlocked accounts, that do not require a password to take an action.